# How do I make this facilitator display the answer? I have a caller program that uses the mutator to set the variables

Tags: java

I try to run my code and everytime I do the Aquarius Facilitator shows 0.000. Does it have anything to do with the int and double as being my variables and the int causing my answer to trunkaid? Thanks for the help

This is my Program

```
public class JRambolus
{
public JRambolus(){}
public JRambolus(double A)
{
    Lengtus = A;
}
public JRambolus(double A, int B)
{
    Lengtus = A;
    Actus   = B;
}
    //mutator
void SetLengtus( double A )
{
    Lengtus = A;
}
    //mutator
void SetActus(int A)
{
    Actus = A;
}
    //accessor 
double GetLengtus()
{
    return Lengtus;
}
    //accessor 
int GetActus()
{
    return Actus;
}
//Facilitator
double Arius()
{ 
    return 3*Lengtus+(1/2*Actus);
}
double Aquarius()
{
    return 4/3*((1/2*Lengtus)+(2/5*Actus));
}
double Nebulus()
{
    return (Math.pow(Lengtus,2)+Math.pow(Actus,3/2))*4/3;
}

//Memeber Varibales
private double Lengtus;
private int Actus;
  }
```

This is my calling program

```
public class JShower
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    JRambolus FullRambolus = new JRambolus();

    //Calling out the the system
    System.out.printf("%43s %4s %8.3f%n"    ,"The Arius of FullRambolus is"   ,"=", FullRambolus.   Arius() );
    System.out.printf("%46s %s %8.3f%n"     ,"The Aquarius of FullRambolus is","=", FullRambolus.Aquarius() );
    System.out.printf("%45s %2s %8.3f%n%n%n","The Lengtus of FullRambolus is" ,"=", FullRambolus.Nebulus () );






    JRambolus DefaultRambolus  = new JRambolus();
    //Calling the Mutator From JRambolus
    DefaultRambolus.SetLengtus(6);
    DefaultRambolus.SetActus(3);




    //Calling out to the system
    System.out.printf("%46s %4s %8.3f%n","The Arius of DefaultRambolus is"   ,"=", DefaultRambolus.   Arius() );
    System.out.printf("%49s %s %8.3f%n" ,"The Aquarius of DefaultRambolus is","=", DefaultRambolus.Aquarius() );
    System.out.printf("%48s %2s %8.3f%n","The Nebulus of DefaultRambolus is" ,"=", DefaultRambolus.Nebulus () );




    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you elaborate what and how you want to display.

Comment: Standard Java convention is to use initial lower-case letters on names of member variables and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing integer division with doubles, which can lead to unexected results.

The statement should be

```
return 4d/3d*((1d/2d*Lengtus)+(2d/5d*Actus));
```

In your original statement, `4/3` is calculated using integer division, giving the value `1`.  More critically, so are `1/2` (result: 0) and `2/5` (also zero) giving a return value of `0.0D`

Comment: Thanks you so much. This makes a lot of sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You're **returning** the value.  Take a look [here](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java101/java101.html) and see how they handle the printing/displaying of variables.